# Why php eval function refuse MySQL statements on GoDaddy hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, eval

I have a working PHP code to connect to MySQL database. I need to use same code within eval function to evaluate. However both following codes are working on some free test hosting accounts, and the second one is not working on my client's GoDaddy (Paid) hosting account.

This code seems to be working:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','my_user','my_password','my_db');
```

However, this code is not working:

```
eval("$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','my_user','my_password','my_db');");
```

It would be highly appreciated if someone can point me in the right direction to solve this or show some working code sample.

Comment: "not working" is rather vague.

Comment: Have you considered contacting GoDaddy and asking them about this particular issue? Do you think you can provide details about your problem?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes with escapes `eval('$con = mysqli_connect(\'localhost\',\'my_user\',\'my_password\',\'my_db\');');`? Also, using `eval()` is generally frowned upon due to security issues in your script. Is there possibly a better solution you are overlooking?

Comment: It is probably disabled on the server due to possible security expoits. If you need to use this function. You'd have trouble on shared hosting, a vps will be an extremely viable option

Comment: Thanks for replies. Error I got was; This page isn’t working
is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500. When I comment out the eval function page displays without error.

Comment: Thanks Rasclatt. I will try your solution and reply with results. Thanks again